# checkDeath() not being called

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a Tower Defense project and I am running into a little issue.

```
public void loseHealth(int amo) {
            health -= amo;
            checkDeath();
        }
public void checkDeath() {
            if(health == 0) {
                deleteMob();
            }
        }
```

This works, but when I try the following the health reaches zero and the mob does not get deleted. I have been trying to get this working for about 2 days and cannot seem to get it right. I have been unsuccessful at finding something to read that could help but I may not be looking in the right place.

```
    public void loseHealth(int amo) {
        shot = Value.damage[0] += amo;
        health -= shot;
        checkDeath();
    }

    public void checkDeath() {
        if(health == 0) {
            deleteMob();
        }
    }
```

I declared an array and that consists of:

```
public static int[] damage = {5, 10};
```

The reason I have two here is because I have two towers I am trying to have do different damage. Right now I just want to get it working I can do the part for the different towers. If there is more information you need please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your `health` variable is getting decreased below 0. Therefore, `health == 0` will always return `false`. Try the following instead:

```
public void checkDeath() {
    if(health <= 0) {
        deleteMob();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid, I should have known that. I guess everything is a learning experience. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks possible that your loseHealth method could produce a negative value for health. If this is the case then your `checkDeath` method would have to use `if(health <=0)` for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're checking explicitly if your health integer is at 0. Most likely, the mob's health counter is a negative number after getting inflicted damage.

Use

```
if(health <= 0)
```

Instead of

```
if(health == 0)
```